# Jsoup - applying a search of a <form> <input> tag

Tags: java, html, forms, input, jsoup

I got this site http://findmusicbylyrics.com/ which uses a `<form>` and a `<input>` tag in order to input and submit the search.

**relevant HTML:**

```
<form action="/search.php" id="cse-search-box">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-1936238606905173:1893984547" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cof" value="FORID:10" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
        <input type="search" name="q" id="main_search_box" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" id="main_search_button" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to use `Jsoup` to enter my `String` ,applying the search and get the `HTML` page/pages of the search.

**My code:**

```
try {
    HtmlPage htmlPage = new HtmlPage(Jsoup.connect("http://findmusicbylyrics.com/").get()); // Connect to the HTML page
    Element formElement = htmlPage.getElement("form#cse-search-box"); // <form action="/search.php" id="cse-search-box"> tag
    Element searchBoxElement = formElement.select("input#main_search_box").first(); // <input type="search" name="q" id="main_search_box" autofocus="autofocus" /> tag
    Element searchBoxElement2 = searchBoxElement.attr("input", "Love");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do i keep from here if i keep from here, because I don't know if `Jsoup` can handle those kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lucky, the site is using `GET` to pass information to the search page.

What I would do if I were you is use the direct URL of the search page and concatenate my keyword. Do not forget to replace spaces between words with `+`

```
String keyWord = "hello, its me".replace(" ", "+");
HtmlPage(Jsoup.connect("http://findmusicbylyrics.com/search.php?cx=partner-pub-1936238606905173%3A1893984547&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=" + keyWord + "&sa=Search+Lyrics").get());
```

Comment: Ok i changed it. But what I do after i get the `HTML` page with my keyWord in the search box? the click on the search button occurs? Thnaks.

Comment: @God No Click is needed actually. This will charge the page immediately with the results in it.

Comment: Well i got it. It just gives me back the `HTML` document after the search has submitted. Pretty clever.

Comment: @God That's it :) You're lucky they sent the search query through the URL and not via a POST :)